# how to fix Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel in EditText.SetText on UiThread

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm having issue with an application wrote in Xamarin for a Zebra TC72 barcode reader (Android 8.1 API 27)
On every read of a barcode I'm writing the barcode in a EditText and update a ListView. I saw that the usually happen in the SetText line after 150-400 barcode scanned giving to me the below exception:

> Errore: Eccezione non gestita 
>   System.Exception: CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
>     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in :0 
>     at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in :0 
>     at Android.Widget.TextView.SetText (Java.Lang.ICharSequence text, Android.Widget.TextView+BufferType type) [0x0004b] in <77a894fb7faf4f5db507f6af453111b6>:0 
>     at Android.Widget.TextView.SetText (System.String text, Android.Widget.TextView+BufferType type) [0x0000d] in <77a894fb7faf4f5db507f6af453111b6>:0 
>     at Droid.ScannerActivity_V1+<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0 () [0x00016] in <8d309dd0ee354f4e8a44f83989b7979a>:0 
>     at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <77a894fb7faf4f5db507f6af453111b6>:0 
>     at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <77a894fb7faf4f5db507f6af453111b6>:0 
>     at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.6(intptr,intptr)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

what I was able to see from the profiler is a large number of thread. (I don't understand if is the same one called over and over again as should be by using runOnUiThread or if a new thread is called everytime). Ater a large number of successful call the next RunOnUiThread fail to set the text in the editText and my application goes in the Show(exc) which is also using RunOnUiThread for display a Toast of the Exception Message. This second call of RunOnUiThread crash too causing the application to crash completely

```
    public void Write_returned_BC(EditText v)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Scanned_Data != null) //Scanned_Data is my Barcode
                    {
                        RunOnUiThread(() => v.SetText(Scanned_Data,TextView.BufferType.Normal));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Show(exc);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would suggest you do is the following:

Add the RunOnMainThread method in your BaseActivity if you have one or add this to your MainActivity:

```
 public bool IsMainThread => Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M
? Looper.MainLooper.IsCurrentThread
: Looper.MyLooper() == Looper.MainLooper;

public void RunOnMainThread(Action action)
{
  if (IsMainThread) action();
  else RunOnUiThread(action);
}
```

What the above method does is it only calls the RunOnUiThread method if you are not on MainThread already so this makes sure you do not create additional threads.

Secondly, I would suggest you do is use the C# provided properties instead of using the SetText method i.e is the Text property.

```
 RunOnMainThread(() => v.Text=Scanned_Data);
```

Also when dealing with strings the best thing to do for null checks is use the `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` Method which will directly return a boolean so the if would become something like.

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Scanned_Data))
```

Comment: Hi,
first of all thanks for your reply!
Yes, I do have a BaseActivity so I will try your solution. 
I tried to use the SetText method because on another question here I found that a possible releated issue to this exceptio was resolved using this method instead of the .Text property.
I already do a null check value for my string before save it into Scanned_Data, but thanks for this second hint also

Comment: Maybe you should take a look with the above solution I have never faced any issue with this.

Comment: I followed the instruction as above (except for the .Text part tha I will defenly try but I had no improvement. The funny stuff is that as test I wrote manually a calling to all the methods called by the scanner (including the piece of code that normally crash) and replicate this code 700 times on 700 different barcodes, run the code and received no issue. This stuff is getting complicated

Comment: I tried the .Text solution but without any results.
I also tried to lunch onBackPressed in the catch of this exception for closing the form bu, after closing the form and come back to the main menu of my application when I try to re-open the form the same exception will pop up crashing again my app.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue.
The problem looks like something related with the scanner implementation.
I redo the scanner management from scratch using the example provided by Zebra as base for my work

thanks everybody for the help